# module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'cvtcolor'

Tags: python, opencv

I never used python and openCV before and I don't know what is the problem.

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
import cv2
import time

last_time = time.time()
while(True):
        screen = np.array(ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0,40, 640, 480)))
        print('Loop took {} second'.format(time.time()-last_time))
        cv2.imshow('window', cv2.cvtcolor(screen, cv2.COLOR_BRG2RGB))
        if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
                cv2.destroyAllWindow()
                break
```

this is the code, can somebody help me understand the problem?

thanks

[the code with the error, sorry for the language translate from italian](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ff3ak.png)

[Error duting the runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/noxCC.png)

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same `cvtColor` found in the list. Can you please add traceback

Comment: can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: Post screen shot here.

Comment: I posted the screen shot on the question

Comment: Seriously? Ur error has nothing to do with `cvtColor` should be `COLOR_BGR2RGB` you are making mistake in syntax.

Comment: where is the syntax error? and I posted what he say when I start the program

Comment: You have mentioned `COLOR_BRG2RGB` instead of `COLOR_BGR2RGB`. Gn lugi (2am ist) try to read the error and debug :) you will learn by practicing

Comment: omg I lost 8 hour for this error XD, thank you for the help

Comment: Ciao Luigi. I hope you got what I told you.

Comment: I rewrited this program several times and I made the same mistake over and over thanks for the help, now it works

Comment: Can you close this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

should be `cvtColor` as `cvtcolor` renamed to `cvtColor`

**source:**
https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_colorspaces/py_colorspaces.html

Comment: Can you tell me your version @Lugizaccaria

Comment: the version of python is 3.9.2, the version of opencv 4.5.1.48

Comment: @Lugizaccaria: do `dir(cv2)` and look for cvtcolor in the list

Comment: where I have to do this?I use python since this morning sorry

Comment: `print(dir(cv2)) ` --> will return all the  functions associated with it.

Comment: I found it in the list and I found also the COLOR_BRG2RGB

Comment: @Lugizaccaria: Did you find `cvtColor`??